Getting Error in my mongodb atlas: Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000
I got mails from mongodb that says Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000
I have checked the mongodb console and found that my this query :
const chats = await Chat.aggregate([
                        {
                          $match: { 
                                roomId: r.roomId._id, 
                                createdAt: { $lte: removedOn, $gte: addedOn }, 
                                updatedAt: { $gte: new Date(lastSynced) }, 
                                deletedFor: { $ne: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(args.userId) } 
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                                from: 'chat-reactions',               
                                localField: '_id',                    
                                foreignField: 'messageId',            
                                as: 'reactions'                      
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $unwind: {
                                path: "$reactions",
                                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true     
                            }
                        },
                        {
                          $lookup: {
                            from: 'chats',  
                            localField: 'parent_message',
                            foreignField: '_id',
                            as: 'parent_message'
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          $unwind: {
                            path: '$parent_message',
                            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
                          }
                        },
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                              from: 'users',  
                              localField: 'from',
                              foreignField: '_id',
                              as: 'from'
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            $unwind: {
                              path: '$from',
                              preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true 
                            }
                          },
                        {
                          $project: {
                            roomId: 1,
                            message: 1,
                            message_type: 1,
                            attachment: 1,
                            isBroadcastMessage: 1,
                            isDeletedForAll: 1,
                            isForwarded: 1,
                            storyId: 1,
                            isStoryRemoved: 1,
                            resId: 1,
                            seenCount: 1,
                            deliveredCount: 1,
                            createdAt: 1,
                            updatedAt: 1,
                            unreadCount: 1,
                            shouldDisappear: 1,
                            disappearTime: 1,
                            from: {
                                _id: "$from._id",
                                name: "$from.name",
                                phone_number: "$from.phone_number"
                            },
                            'parent_message.from': 1,
                            'parent_message.roomId': 1,
                            'parent_message.isDeletedForAll': 1,
                            'parent_message.isForwarded': 1,
                            'parent_message.storyId': 1,
                            'parent_message.isStoryRemoved': 1,
                            'parent_message.message': 1,
                            'parent_message.message_type': 1,
                            'parent_message.attachment': 1,
                            reactions: 1  
                          }
                        }
                      ]);

my this aggregation pipeline examined 26K keys and returned 101 record and in some cases it searches Millions keys.
Previousaly I used these indexes in my mongo db atlas
_id_
room_id
updated_at
roomId_1_deletedFor_1_createdAt_1_updatedAt_1
roomId_1_from_1_unreadCount_1_createdAt_1
roomId_1__id_1_from_1_unreadCount_1_autocreated
broadcastMessageId_1
createdAt_1

my chat's table have most of the records it has 191K records.
I also looked at my rooms table and found that there is one room doc that have key called members (array of object) with over 18K Records
may please anyone help me with this situation, I am stuck in this.
Expecting a way by I can resolve errors coming from mongodb by either optimizing the query or by optimizing indexing of mongodb.

Note that the examined/returned alert is for the entire database instance, not any one query.  Also, this query that examined 26k to return 101 has a scanned/returned ratio of 257, so that is not your worst culprit.
